# Does "external declaration or definition" not mean what I think?

Tags: c++, header-files, language-lawyer

#### 17.6.2.2 Headers [using.headers]

> 3) **A translation unit shall include a header only outside of any
>   external declaration or definition**, and shall include the header
>   lexically before the first reference in that translation unit to any
>   of the entities declared in that header.

If my interpretation is correct:

```
extern "C"
{
   #include "smth.h"
}
```

is illegal (and there's a lot of it out there).

Am I missinterpreting? Do "external declaration" and "external definition" mean something else (in this context)?

Comment: Is that `smth.h` header file from libsmth?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo nope :) sorry :)

Comment: Isn't `extern "C"` a _linkage specification_ rather than an external declaration thing?

Comment: @Mat My thoughts exactly, but I don't see what else "external declaration" might mean *in this context*.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I agree that it must mean this. It also makes sense to mean this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *header* is defined in the standard as where elements of the C++ standard library are declared or defined. That doesn't include the user's `.h` files. See §17.6.1.2:

> Each element of the C++ standard library is declared or defined (as appropriate) in a *header*.
>
> The C++ standard library provides 52 *C++ library headers*, as shown in Table 14.
>
> The facilities of the C standard Library are provided in 26 additional headers, as shown in Table 15.

So the example you gave is fine (as long as the `.h` file doesn't itself include some standard library headers). However, this wouldn't be:

```
extern "C"
{
   #include <string>
}
```

To further back up the seperation between headers and source files (which include `.h` files), the `#include` preprocessing directive is defined to include "headers" with the `<h-char-sequence>` syntax and to include "source files" with the `"q-char-sequence"` syntax (§16.2). So your `#include "smth.h"` is including a source file, not a header. A source file is defined as the text of a program, which together with the headers it includes makes up a translation unit:

> The text of the program is kept in units called source files in this International Standard. A source file together with all the headers (17.6.1.2) and source files included (16.2) via the preprocessing directive `#include`, less any source lines skipped by any of the conditional inclusion (16.1) preprocessing directives, is called a translation unit.

I think the aim of such wording is to decouple the standard library headers from their representation. There's no reason they have to be stored as C++ source files, even though they typically are. Including a particular header just has to have the effect of making the appropriate declarations available to the program.

Comment: Well, the quote says "header", not "library header". Not saying you're wrong, but your argumentation isn't complete.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore The italics on "*header*" are in the standard, meaning that it's the definition of the word. As far as I can tell, the *headers* include the C++ library headers and the C++ headers for C library facilities (and not the C headers, which are defined separately in appendix D).

Comment: Does it also mean it's exclusive? I.e. "Each element of the C++ standard library is declared or defined (as appropriate) in a header." => no other elements can be defined in a header / no other headers exist?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I suppose it's debatable, but the specification for `#include` helps back it up.

Comment: Yeah, your edit makes sense. Kinda misleading I guess (the wording in the standard).

Answer (score 1):

I think [Joseph Mansfield's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16506229/2756719) mostly correctly interprets the word "header" (it refers only to the standard library headers defined in §17.6.1.2 [headers]), except that I think it also includes the C headers described in appendix D, as footnote 176 (in N3936) refers to both `<iso646.h>` and `<ciso646>` as "standard header". This answer focuses on the meaning of the phrase *external declaration or definition*.

It appears that this particular sentence in the C++ standard was borrowed from the C standard. The same phrasing seems to be present in the C89 standard, at least according to [this unofficial version](http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt), and is present in both C99 and C11.

While the C++ standard doesn't define "external declaration or definition", these terms are defined in the C standard (quoting N1256 §6.9):

> the unit of program text after preprocessing is a translation unit,
>   which consists of a sequence of external declarations.  These are
>   described as "external" because they appear outside any function (and
>   hence have file scope). [...]
>
> An external definition is an external declaration that is also a
>   definition of a function or an object.

The C grammar for a *translation-unit* is:

```
translation-unit:
    external-declaration
    translation-unit external-declaration
external-declaration:
    function-definition
    declaration
```

Now, the corresponding description of a translation unit in the C++ standard is (§3.5 [basic.link]):

> A translation unit consists of a sequence of declarations.

And the grammar is simply

```
translation-unit:
    declaration-seq_opt
```

In short, in C, a translation unit is a sequence of *external declarations*, and in C++, it is a sequence of *declarations*. Thus it appears that the word "external" in the C++ standard is a historical artifact caused by the borrowing, and the quoted sentence is meant to prohibit including standard library headers in *any* declaration or definition of whatever sort.